# Adding leaflet pop-up information to a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I want to add the pop-up data to a specific div, `tab4`, I made. I posted the code in my question. This is what I have so far. If I `console.log(d.html)` I get the correct output but it doesn't show up in my div yet. I think I'm missing something to bind or push it to the `tab4` div but I'm not sure.

```
window["mapDataLayer"] = L.geoJson(geojson, {
         onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
           layer.on({
                click: function showResultsInDiv() {
                    var d = document.getElementById('tab4');
                    d.html = "";
                        for (prop in feature.properties){
                        d.html += prop+": "+feature.properties[prop]+"<br>";
                        }
                    console.log(d.html);
                    // I Think i need a line of code here that pushes it to the 'tab4' div.
                }
            }); }
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it, needed to use `innerHTML` instead of `html`. So this the complete code now:

```
window["mapDataLayer"] = L.geoJson(geojson, {
         onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
           layer.on({
                click: function showResultsInDiv() {
                    var d = document.getElementById('tab4');
                    d.innerHTML = "";
                        for (prop in feature.properties){
                        d.innerHTML += prop+": "+feature.properties[prop]+"<br>";
                        }
                    console.log(d.innerHTML);
                }
            }); }
    }).addTo(map);
```